# How would a SSL tunnel be exploited?

Tags: tls, tunneling

I am looking at our CI (Bamboo) Server initiating an outbound connection to setup a SSL tunnel to an agent running on an AWS ec2 instance. As per the documentation:

> All traffic sent between the agents located in EC2 and the Bamboo
>   server is tunnelled through an SSL-encrypted tunnel. The tunnel will
>   be initiated from the Bamboo Server to the EC2 instance, which means
>   that you don't need to allow any inbound connections to your server.
>   You will need to permit outbound traffic from the server on the tunnel
>   port.

Now I understand what a SSL tunnel is and this may sound like a naive question, but what are some ways a SSL tunnel can be exploited to send malicious data to the CI server if the ec2 instance is compromised?

Reference:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/elastic-bamboo-security-289277195.html

Comment: good one, but this question seems to be something for the Bamboo folks, as one can send whatever inside that tunnel, it is up to the Bamboo Server to handle those incoming data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, normally, the Bamboo server is the one sending code and instructions to the EC2 instances.

This means that assuming that there is no remote code exploits in Bamboo that allows the EC2 to command the Bamboo server, then these are the possible things that the attacker can do:

1. Steal source code
2. Return fake test results, corrupting your results
3. If you used passing tests on CI to trigger continuous deployment, then it can trigger deployment
4. If your CI builds a package or image as a build artefact, which can later be deployed to production, then the compromised EC2 can inject malicious code into the build.

The SSL tunnel is the least of your worry; all it does is provide a secure tunnel between your Bamboo server and EC2.